# error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc

I have wasted two weeks to figure this out but no success so far.
I have installed gsl-1.16 on linux server and am trying to run matlab program (not written by me) that runs C code but I always get this error 
 error: gsl/gsl_vector.h: No such file or directory.
I am not sure why.  I have installed gsl several times and everything went fine (after messing up a few times.) Now when I run even a simple c program with 
gsl/gsl_vector.h, I get the same error. I can open this file gsl/gsl_vector.h using vi but still program does not locate it. I have the

gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC)

I installed the gsl on my mac a while ago (I believe using the same method) and that worked perfectly fine but on linux it is driving me insane.
Please HELP!!!
Fiona

Comment: Did you include the path to the include directory in your GCC commandline?

Comment: Yes, I did try that too. And also I tried to put the file in that folder where gsl/gsl_vector.h exists but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by setting 
C_INCLUDE_PATH